# deactivate rolling circles when open an other link/site of my website

Tags: magento2, page

When I open any page of my website https://www.agoshop.at everytime I will get scrolling circles and after that I will see my new page.
This is very disturbing. Therefore I will ask how I can deactivate this.
Here a picture of the circles:
[image]

Hope someone can help me there.
kindly regards for any answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Check theme documentation if there is any setting to enable/disable this loader.

**Solution 2**

Find following code in your theme file/setting and remove it.

```
<div id="loading-fixed">
    <div id="loading-center-fixed">
        <div id="loading-center-absolute-fixed">
            <div class="object-fixed" id="object_four"></div>
            <div class="object-fixed" id="object_three"></div>
            <div class="object-fixed" id="object_two"></div>
            <div class="object-fixed" id="object_one"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
require([
        'jquery'
    ], function ($) {
        'use strict';
        $(window).load(function() {
            $('#loading-fixed').delay(500).fadeOut('slow');
        });
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            var myVarloader = setInterval(function(){ setLoaderTime() }, 1000);
            function setLoaderTime() {
                $('#loading-fixed').delay(500).fadeOut('slow');
                clearInterval(myVarloader);
            }
        });
});
</script>
```

**Solution 3**

Add following css rule in head section.

```
<style>
#loading-fixed{ display:none !important;}
</style>
```

Give preference to Solution 1.

Comment: Hi!
Thanks a lot for your answer.
I checked that I use Rokanthemes and could find there a setting with 
Enable page preloader which I switch to no.
kindly regards